# Linq for filtering data into object with multiple fields, one of them being List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

**I'm trying to do transform something like this:**

| Id | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id1val1 | id1val2 | id1val3 |
| 2 | id2val1 | id2val2 | id2val3 |
| 1 | id1val1 | id1val2 | id1val4 |
| 3 | id3val1 | id3val2 | id3val3 |

**Into something like this:**

| Id | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id1val1 | id1val2 | id1val3,id2val4 |
| 2 | id2val1 | id2val2 | id2val3 |
| 3 | id3val1 | id3val2 | id3val3 |

So I have a class type that look like this:

```
public RetType{
  int id {get; set;}
  string Value1  {get; set;}
  string Value2  {get; set;}
  List<string> Value3  {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a LINQ method for obtaining this result, being the fact that I have an object obtained by another LINQ that looks like this:

```
var result = Linq_query...select new{id = tableX.idVal, Value1 = tableY.val1, Value2 = tableX.val2, Value3 = tableZ.val3}
```

I've tried something like this:

```
var groupResult = result.GroupBy(r => r.id).Select(grp =>.ToList()).ToList();
```

But it's not returning what I expect, it just grouping both id=1 rows into an array.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to merge duplicit records into one record where in value3 will be unique values from merged objects ?

Comment: (https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/50662012/how-to-create-a-stuff-and-xml-path-sql--in-linq-or-lambda)

Comment: @puko I have a form with some inputs and a multiple select dropdown list( That Value3 actually comes from this ddlist), which is saved in my database in two records(only difference between them being that Value3) -> now I want to display these values in a template and group that Value3 values that are coresponding to only 1 record in fact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your intension correctly. Now assuming that Value2 would not change when id changes (since you haven't mentioned how to handle such a scenario), you could do the following,

```
public class RetType{
  public int id {get; set;}
  public string Value1  {get; set;}
  public string Value2  {get; set;}
  public List<string> Value3  {get; set;}
}

var finalResult = result.GroupBy(x=>x.Id)
                          .Select(x=> new RetType
                          {
                            id = x.First().Id,
                            Value2 = x.First().Value2,
                            Value3 = x.Select(c=>c.Value3).ToList()
                          })
```

Do note that in your `RetType` you have used `List<string>` to represent the Value3. If you need to have it as comma separated string (as in the table in OP), you could use a `string.Join`

```
var finalResult = result.GroupBy(x=>x.Id)
                          .Select(x=> new RetType
                          {
                            id = x.First().Id,
                            Value2 = x.First().Value2,
                            Value3 = string.Join(",",x.Select(c=>c.Value3))
                          })
```

Where the RetType is defined as

```
public class RetType{
  public int id {get; set;}
  public string Value1  {get; set;}
  public string Value2  {get; set;}
  public string Value3  {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: public List<string> Value3  {get; set;}

Comment: That's the first case mentioned in the answer ? I had given the second options since your table in the same had comma separated value (may be only for demonstration purpse)

Comment: Sorry I was fast reading. First answer did the trick, I there a way of putting empty string( "") instead of "null" ?(I have record with null values for Value3)